# React, разница в месте определения state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel, es7

Использую `ReactJS`, пишу на `ECMASсript 7` и использую транслятор `BabelJS`.

Есть два варианта объявления свойства `state`:

Первый:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      total: null,
      next: null,
      operation: null,
    };
```

Второй:

```
state = {
    total: null,
    next: null,
    operation: null,
  }
```

Есть ли разница между двумя этими вариантами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В рамках `ES7` разницы по сути нет, оба вызова ведут к тому, что из всех методов класса, нам будет доступна ссылка `this.state`, а самая большая и главная разница тут в том, что все современные браузеры, пока вообще не поддерживают `ES7`, и для второго варианта, вам нужно использовать транслятор, первый же вариант, абсолютно `ES6` совместим, соответственно поддерживается почти всеми современными браузерами. И тут образовывается ситуация, если вы уже активно используете трансляторы, то вы также смело можете использовать и объявление свойств в стиле `ES7`. Но лучше конечно, не использовать трансляторы вообще.

К тому же многие люди сейчас все еще живут в `ES5` стиле, когда есть модный молодежный `ES6`, который еще так молод...

Comment: "Так-то конечно есть, первый вариант можно обьявить только внутри класса, и при этом внутри класса после этого, по ссылке this.state будет доступен объект":
 внутри класса и при втором варианте доступен this.state

"А также мы вызываем конструктор родителя.":
 да, вызываем, что это меняет?

"к тому же в рамках современного JS не верное, так как не указана не одна из существующих конструкций для объявления переменных.":
 - там все верно, не нужно объявлять переменную - это называется инициализатор свойства (ES7), а Babel все успешно транспилирует.

Comment: @ВикторМеладзе вот это "там все верно", как и не верное, вы не указали не весь контекст, не то что пишите на  `ES7`. 

По поводу "Да вызываем, что это меняет", это акцент.

Comment: Но если вы пишите на ES7, то разницы конечно нет, оба варинта будут идентичны, вот только первый вариант будет удачно работать и без очень ресурсоемких трансляторов, а второму как ран нужен  `BabelJS`.

Comment: Для работы с React необходим Babel, для транспиляции JSX в JS, не использовать его невозможно. Да и при конечной сборке остается лишь один файл bundle.js с ES5 (!)

Comment: Но все же, ваш вопрос не по реакту, и лучше концентрировать внимание на таких деталях как `ES7`, чтобы могли ответить те кто знают "разницу" но не знают `React` например.

Comment: У меня в заголовке первое слово - React ;)
Но все равно спасибо, надеюсь и вам была полезна эта дискуссия

Comment: @ВикторМеладзе удачи вам. (Нарушаю...)